# Angular popup with dynamic template and controller

Tags: angularjs

I have found the following code that produces a popup window.

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'myModal']);

angular.module("myModal", []).directive("myModal", function ($modal, $timeout) {
"use strict";
return {
  template: '<div ng-click="clickMe(rowData)" ng-transclude></div>',
  replace: true,
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
    rowData: '&myModal' 
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.clickMe = function () {
        $modal.open({
        template: "<div>Created By:" + scope.rowData().data + "</div>"
                    + "<div class=\"modal-footer\">"
                    + "<button class=\"btn btn-primary\" ng-click=\"ok()\">OK</button>"
                    + "<button class=\"btn btn-warning\" ng-click=\"cancel()\">Cancel</button>"
                    + "</div>",
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close({ test: "test"});
            };

            $scope.cancel = function () {

            };

            $timeout(function () {
                        $(".modal-dialog").draggable();

                        var resizeOpts = {
                            handles: "all", autoHide: true
                        };

                        $(".modal-dialog").resizable(resizeOpts);
                    }, 0);
        },
        backdrop: "static"
    });
    }
  }
};
});
```

I would like to make this code generic and assign templates and their controllers on the fly. I guess I could specify a template with controller built-in but want to avoid doing that.

Thanks

Comment: This is too vague/broad in my opinion... Show what you tried to make it "more generic". What exactly does "more generic" mean, to begin with? Which template needs to be customized (the modal or the button)? Don't answer in comments - these are just example of vagueness of the question.

Comment: More generic means I want to provide templates and their controllers at the runtime, thus the provided code would be acting a generic popup mechanism for anything that needs to be shown in a popup.

Comment: Still vague... and let me repeat: don't answer in comments - provide the details by editing the question.. The question lacks too much for comments to suffice: no examples of desired usage, no exact parameters of what should be possible and what shouldn't be, and no attempts to show what has been tried.

Comment: This is a valid question, just remove so much of code and ask for how to make this a more componentised code

Comment: I think this [dynamicTemplate service](https://github.com/BurakAkyildiz/angularJs-dynamic-conditional-templates) helpfull for this case.